# JQuery drag and drop with validation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, drag-and-drop

I have created a simple tabbed JQuery drag and drop system, which is populated with the relevant data from my database.

http://ignitethatdesign.com/phoneShop/test1.php

My main goal is to eventually create a simple phone package system, by dragging and dropping the various elements needed when choosing a phone contract, such as the price of the phone, the network costs, and other variables into the 'Final Package' tab for a grand total of how much it would cost when the user submits it.

I only want to select one option from each of the tabs to go into the 'final package' tab, e.g.

Make: Nokia Lumia 800. Minutes: 100. And so on.

My problem is that I can drag as many of the options from each tab into any tab when I want to take only one from each and put them in the 'final package'.

```
<style>
    #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li, #sortable3 li, #sortable4 li { margin: 0 5px 5px     5px; padding: 5px; font-size: 1.2em; width: 120px; }
</style>

<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3, #sortable4, #sortable5" ).sortable().disableSelection();

    var $tabs = $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

    var $tab_items = $( "ul:first li", $tabs ).droppable({
        accept: ".connectedSortable li",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            var $item = $( this );
            var $list = $( $item.find( "a" ).attr( "href" ) )
                .find( ".connectedSortable" );

            ui.draggable.hide( "slow", function() {
                $tabs.tabs( "select", $tab_items.index( $item ) );
                $( this ).appendTo( $list ).show( "slow" );
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="dragDrop">
 <?php

 mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password") or die ('Unable to Connect MySQL');
 mysql_select_db("database") or die ('Unable to select Database'); 
 ?>

<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#Models">Make</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Minutes">Minutes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Texts">Texts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Data">Data</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Final Package</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="Models">
    <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable ui-helper-reset">
    <?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phone_tbl where category = 'Model'") or     die(mysql_error());
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
 echo "<li id=\"item_=".$row['id']."\"><div>".$row['label']."</div></li>";
 }
?>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="Minutes">
    <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable ui-helper-reset">
    <?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phone_tbl where category = 'Minutes'") or     die(mysql_error());
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
 echo "<li id=\"item_=".$row['id']."\"><div>".$row['label']."</div></li>";
 }
?>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="Texts">
    <ul id="sortable3" class="connectedSortable ui-helper-reset">
    <?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phone_tbl where category = 'Texts'") or     die(mysql_error());
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
 echo "<li id=\"item_=".$row['id']."\"><div>".$row['label']."</div></li>";
 }
?>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="Data">
    <ul id="sortable4" class="connectedSortable ui-helper-reset">
    <?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phone_tbl where category = 'Data'") or die(mysql_error());
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
 echo "<li id=\"item_=".$row['id']."\"><div>".$row['label']."</div></li>";
 }
?>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <ul id="sortable5" class="connectedSortable ui-helper-reset">
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

In what way can I validate each option being added to the final table, so that after one option from each tab is added to the 'final package' tab, no more can be added.

Thanks.

JB.

Comment: I guess this isn't a good question